# Add method to an instanced object

Tags: ruby

```
obj = SomeObject.new

def obj.new_method
  "do some things"
end

puts obj.new_method
> "do some things"
```

This works ok. However, I need to do same thing inside an existing method:

```
def some_random_method
  def obj.new_method
    "do some things"
  end
end
```

Works ok as well, but having a method inside a method looks pretty horrible. The question is, is there any alternate way of adding such a method?

Comment: Are you sure the second snippet of code works? Because I suppose it should be accepting `obj` as a method argument first to define a singleton method over it.

Comment: Just scroll down a bit. SO's algorithm sometimes puts newer answers at the top.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look farther in future.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In ruby 1.9+, there's a better way of doing this using `define_singleton_method`, as follows:

```
obj = SomeObject.new

obj.define_singleton_method(:new_method) do
  "do some things"
end
```

Comment: What will happen if I use `@field` inside of this `do` block? Will I access a field from current class, or will it use field of `obj`?

Comment: Haven't really tested this properly, but as far as I can tell the mixin and this approach are not equivalent. This has access to outside values, whereas a mixin does not.

Answer (score 57):

Use a Mixin.

```
module AdditionalMethods
  def new_method
    "do some things"
  end
end

obj = SomeObject.new
obj.extend(AdditionalMethods)

puts obj.new_method
> "do some things"
```

Answer (score 23):

There are several ways to achieve this, and they are all related to the singleton class:

1. You can use `class <<` idiom to open the singleton class definition:

   ```
    obj = Object.new
    class << obj
      def my_new_method
         ...
      end
    end
   ```
2. Or you can use `define_singleton_method` on the obj:

   ```
    obj = Object.new
    obj.define_singleton_method(:my_new_method) do
         ...
    end
   ```
3. You can also use `define_method` from the singleton class:

   ```
    obj = Object.new
    obj.singleton_class.define_method(:my_new_method) do
         ...
    end
   ```
4. Or you can use `def` directly:

   ```
    obj = Object.new
    def obj.my_new_method
         ...
    end
   ```

Pay attention to example 3, I think the concept of a singleton class becomes clearer on that one. There is a difference between these two examples:

```
    a = Object.new
    b = Object.new
    
    # -- defining a new method in the object's "class" --
    a.class.define_method(:abc) do
      puts "hello abc"
    end
    
    a.abc # prints "hello abc"
    b.abc # also prints "hello abc"

    # -- defining a new method in the object's "singleton class" --
    a.singleton_class.define_method(:bcd) do
      puts "hello bcd"
    end
    
    a.bcd # prints "hello bcd"
    b.bcd # error undefined method
```

This is because every object has its own singleton class:

```
    a = Object.new
    b = Object.new

    p a.class # prints "Object"
    p a.singleton_class # prints "#<Class:#<Object:0x000055ebc0b84438>>"

    p b.class # also prints "Object"
    p b.singleton_class # prints "#<Class:#<Object:0x000055ebc0b84410>>" (a different reference address)
```

Comment: Hi, there is spelling error. The define_sigleton_method which in 2's code should be  define_singleton_method.

Answer (score 8):

Just an interesting point to note:

if you had instead gone:

```
def my_method
    def my_other_method; end
end
```

Then `my_other_method` would actually be defined on the CLASS of the object not withstanding that the receiver of`my_method` is an instance.

However if you go (as you did):

```
def my_method
    def self.my_other_method; end
end
```

Then `my_other_method` is defined on the eigenclass of the instance.

Not directly relevant to your question but kind of interesting nonetheless ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can use modules.

```
module ObjSingletonMethods
  def new_method
    "do some things"
  end
end


obj.extend ObjSingletonMethods

puts obj.new_method # => do some things
```

Now if you need to add more methods to that object, you just need to implement the methods in the module and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Use `instance_eval`:

```
obj = SomeObject.new

obj.instance_eval do
  def new_method
    puts 'do something new'
  end
end

obj.new_method 
> "do something new"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Some
end 

obj = Some.new

class << obj
  def hello 
    puts 'hello'
  end 
end 

obj.hello

obj2 = Some.new
obj2.hello # error
```

Syntax `class << obj` means that we are opening definition of the class for an object. As you probably know we can define Ruby class methods using syntax like this:

```
class Math

    class << self 

        def cos(x)
            ...
        end 

        def sin(x)
            ...
        end 
    end 
end
```

Then we can use those methods like this:

```
Math.cos(1)
```

In Ruby, everything is an object - even classes. `self` here is an object of `Math class` itself (you can access that object with `Math.class`). So syntax `class << self` means we are opening class for `Math class object`. Yes, it means that `Math class` has class too (Math.class.class).

Answer (score 0):

**Another way to use a Mixin**

```
obj = SomeObject.new
class << obj
  include AnotherModule
end
```

This includes all of the methods from `AnotherModule` into the current object.

Answer (score 0):

Using `define_singleton_method` was the cause of an error `singleton can't be dumped` when trying to dump the object latter.

It appears that setting a new attribute to the instantiated object was enough for my need.

```rb
obj = Object.new

obj.class.module_eval { attr_accessor :new_method }
obj.new_method = "do some things"

puts obj.new_method
> "do some things"
```

It partially answer the question as the functions set to `obj` are the ones by `attr_accessor` (and not arbitrary ones). But still, it's a solution when an attribute is enough.