# Add methods to an already-instantiated object?

Tags: ruby, iterator, instantiation, mixins, enumerable

I know how to use `include` to add mixins to a class in Ruby. However, I want to add one or more methods to an ***already instantiated*** object. Is that possible?

For example, the `Rack::File::Iterator` class behaves as an iterator, but it doesn't inherit from `Enumerable`. This means that it doesn't come with a `reduce` method, even though it does contain an `each` method.

I'd like to add the `reduce` method to an already-instantiated `Rack::File::Iterator` object (which I'll refer to as "obj" here), so that I can just do the following ...

```
result = obj.reduce { |a,b| a + b }
```

If I could somehow `include` the `Enumerable` module into the already-instantiated `obj`, I think this would accomplish what I want.

I am only referring to `Rack::File::Iterator` as an example. I'm looking for a general solution which will work with instantiated objects of any class. Furthermore, I'm only using `reduce` as an example, as well. I want this to work with any methods I might wish to add to an object.

Yes, I know how to write my own `reduce` function to which I could pass `obj` and a block as parameters. However, I'd prefer to do this kind of dynamic `include` into an already-instantiated object, if possble.

Thank you in advance.

**ADDENDUM**

I went to the article referenced below (thank you!), and I then realized that there is yet another way to do this which was not mentioned in that article. Therefore, I added another answer to that article with the methodology that I thought of. Here it is, using the example I outlined above ...

```
class << obj
  include Enumerable  # or any other module
end
```

This adds all the methods from `Enumerable` into my object.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is possible.

[Add method to an instanced object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887845/add-method-to-an-instanced-object)

Comment: Thank you. See my **ADDENDUM** to my original question/

Comment: I don't want to be that guy, but in the page referenced, that method was also mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: What was mentioned there is this: `obj.extend(AdditionalMethods)`. That's almost the same, but not quite. My answer adds to that.  (Note: my answer there is "Another way to use mixins").

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181811/27358