# Do methods have to be always inside classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, programming-languages

Hey guys I am new to Ruby. I have a question: Do methods have to be always inside classes?

Comment: @greenhunt2003 : You **are** always in some class, even if you don't define one explicitly. You can see this by i.e. running `ruby -e 'puts self.class'`.

Comment: @user1934428 nitpicking, but: you are always in the context of an object. That object doesn't have to be a class. (`main` is an instance of `Object`, not `Class`)

Comment: @Stefan : Absolutely correct! Thanks for pointing it out. The same applies if we explicitly [add a method to an instance of some class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887845/add-method-to-an-instanced-object).

Comment: @Stefan: More nitpicking: There are *three* different implicit contexts in Ruby. For the purposes of method *lookup* (and a couple of other things such as ivar lookup), you are indeed always in the context of an *object*. But for the purposes of method *definition*, you are always in the context of a *module*. And for the purposes of constant lookup, you are always in the context of … whatever you want to call what constants are looked up in. And then of course, there is local variable lookup, where you are always in the context of a *lexical scope*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: It's always a pleasure to read your comments. Have you ever thought of writing a book in general, and a Ruby book in particular?

Answer (score 2):

Technically they are aways defined inside a class, but this doesn't mean you always need to open a class to define a method.

Here is what might look like a top-level function in other languages:

```
def foo
  puts self
  puts self.class
end
```

If we simply call `foo`, we'll get:

```
main
Object
```

This actually defined a private instance method in the `Object` class. We see that `self` in the top-level scope is a special object called `main`.

---

On the other hand, we can try to call this method on other stuff:

```
'bar'.foo #!> private method `foo' called for "bar":String (NoMethodError)
```

This errorred out as `foo` is private. We can use a special method called `send` to invoke private methods:

```
'bar'.send :foo
```

Gets us:

```
bar
String
```

---

We can also define methods in the so-called singleton classes. You can think of them as classes with only a single instance. For example:

```
foo = 'foo'

def foo.bar
  puts 'baz'
end

foo.bar    # => baz
'quix'.bar # !> undefined method `bar' for "quix":String
'foo'.bar  # !> undefined method `bar' for "foo":String

puts (foo.singleton_class.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods).first
  # => bar
```

Here the `bar` method was defined on the singleton class of `foo`. Note that even another string with the same contents is still a difference instance, hence it doesn't have the `bar` method.

Comment: A more common example is a _class method_, e.g. `def String.foo` – it's also just an instance method created in the class' singleton class.

Comment: @Stefan yep, that's the best example and also it says that there is no true class methods in Ruby as in other languages as it always bound to an object.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts isn't defined in a class, though. See Jörg's answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Hey guys I am new to Ruby. I have a question: Do methods have to be always inside classes?

No.

Methods have to be always inside *modules*. (Class are modules, too.)

Example:

```rb
module Foo
  def bar; end
end
```

There is no class here.

Comment: Oh my, I totally forgot about modules :-)